# xlsx generation in nodejs, along with graphs

Tags: node.js, xlsx

I need to create Excel Sheet report in nodejs, along with some pie/bar charts. The Packages like https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx and https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs doesn't provide the facility to create charts.

Can anyone suggest any methodor existing package so that pie/bar charts can be included in xlsx report in Nodejs?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem and I am looking for the solution as well. 
I have found https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-chart but I don't know yet how to integrate data along with the chart because the plugin generate separate sheet for data and table.

Answer (score 3):

Using https://www.npmjs.com/package/quiche you will get an URL with the image. I´ve tryed to integrated it in exceljs or to save it like an image but seems impossible

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a Google Chart image and insert it in your report. There is https://github.com/ryanrolds/quiche for that.

It will call Google API to generate your image and return the URL. I believe it's not hard to integrate an image from URL into the xls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an npm lib called office-chart.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-chart/v/1.0.26

It will allow you to create xlsx charts in mulisheets and also create pptx with charts.